# Setting Global Variables in JS on Event Trigger - Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, global-variables, zooming, event-listener

I'm using Google Maps API v3 and need to offset markers based on the current zoom level.

I have a global variable current_zoom_level, and an event listener for zoom in/out:

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
 current_zoom_level = map.getZoom();
 alert(current_zoom_level);
});

I've tried this bit in the initialization code and the code that calculates the offset.  The alert displays the correct current zoom level, but when I access it in build_loan_markers() (where I calculate offsets) current_zoom_level is undefined.

function build_loan_markers ()
{
        var offset;
 alert(current_zoom_level);
 if(!window.current_zoom_level){
  window.current_zoom_level = 1;
 }
 offset = 1/(window.current_zoom_level^2);
 alert('zoom: ' + current_zoom_level + ' offset: ' + offset);
        etc..
}

How can I globally set this variable?

Comment: Please format the code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

To make a variable global, simply declare it outside any function definition.

```
var current_zoom_level = 0;

function something() {
   // Add your listener here
}

function build_loan_markers() {
  alert(current_zoom_level);
}
```

You shouldn't need to access your variable as window.current_zoom_level. It was unclear from your code which of the two `alert(current_zoom_level)s` was working, consider posting a link to a site that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: but you can't do it with a variable whose value will be filled in from another trigger function